# A fair die is successively rolled. Let $X$ and $Y$ denote, respectively, the number of rolls necessary to obtain a 6 and a 5. Find $Var[ X|Y = 5]$

Tags: probability, variance

> A fair die is successively rolled. Let $X$ and $Y$ denote,
>   respectively, the number of rolls necessary to obtain a    6 and a 5.
>   Find
>
> $E[ X|Y = 5]$
>
> [How to conceptualize conditional expectation inductively?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176692/how-to-conceptualize-conditional-expectation-inductively)

While reading the question above, I thought about obtaining the (in my opinion, much more difficult) conditional variance. Could someone help me to find  $Var[ X|Y = 5]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the answer to your previous question, the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $Y$ is given by
$$
\mathbb P(X=n\mid Y=m) = \begin{cases}
\frac15\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1},& 1\leqslant n\leqslant m-1\\
\frac16\left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}\left(\frac56\right)^{n-m-1},& n\geqslant m+1.
\end{cases}
$$
So we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X\mid Y=m] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mathbb P(X=n\mid Y=m)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} n\cdot\frac15\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1} + \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty n\cdot\frac16\left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}\left(\frac56\right)^{n-m-1}\\
&= 5-\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{1-m} (m+4) + \left(\frac 45\right)^{m-1}(m+6)\\
&= 5 + 2\left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}
\end{align}
and similarly
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^2\mid Y=m] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2\cdot\mathbb P(X=n\mid Y=m)\\
&= 45-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{m-1} (m (m+8)+36) + \left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}(66 +m(12+m))\\
&=  45 + 2\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{m-1}(2 m+15).
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{Var}(X\mid Y=m) &= \mathbb E[X^2\mid Y=m] - \mathbb E[X\mid Y=m]^2\\
&=45 + 2\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{m-1}(2 m+15) -\left(5 + 2\left(\frac45\right)^{m-1}\right)^2.
\end{align}
For $m=5$, the above evalutes to $9$.